# youtube and soundcloud

Tags: youtube, soundcloud, demo, websites, social-network

Do u use youtube.com and soundcloud.com to show your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use YouTube and SoundCloud. Mostly to host files for my website.

Answer (score 2):

**Video**

I use both Vimeo & Youtube to upload, reason being is I'm never sure which one will catch on and might get a little bit of traction. That said, I always use Vimeo to display my work, it looks better and now works on iPhones.

**Audio**

Soundcloud for sure! I quite like [audioBoo](http://www.audioboo.fm./) to show quick snippets of sounds I like from a random place (recorded on iPhone) - not for professional use, just to share quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I use Soundcloud for my business (sound libraries) and it's been absolutely great. Not only does it drive my work pretty much directly to one of my main customer bases (musicians), it's also serving as a great way to get feedback on my work, along with all the other sharing and viral word-of-mouth stuff that comes with a social platform. It's very tightly focused on one kind of content and that's why it works so well. You can also get very granular with things like permissions, sharing, comments, etc. It even has built-in Creative Commons licenses - if you want them. Their "Premium" account has proven to be well worth it for me.

YouTube, not so much. Unlike Soundcloud, it's like the Wild West. The demographic is, um, everyone in the world. And you have to face a double-sided sword of choosing to either lock down comments and lose out on potential viral spread and community type stuff, or open them up to the wide world of internet morons. I used it for a bit but didn't find it to be of any value. Your mileage may vary.

Vimeo, on the other hand, I like quite a lot. It's rare that I have the need to present video but when I do I use Vimeo. It's got a much higher signal-to-noise ratio and the audience there tends to be seeking out high quality material with genuine interest. Lots of artists and creative types on there.

As an aside, I also like tumblr for both video and audio. Free, easy and a built-in audience of several bazillion people. Very nice platform.

What's nice is that so many of these services talk to each other, so you can post content to one place and it automagically just ends up everywhere. Fun times we live in, the present is so futurey.

Comment: SoundCloud and Vimeo are my choices as well. Vimeo offers a lot more player customization and options than YouTube as well, and the UI is far cleaner for those who hit the site directly, as opposed to watching videos inline on your own site.

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud and Vimeo for me. Youtube is too open, Vimeo gives you more access in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

theres a good saying: "fish where the fish are"

& i agree with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Going to look into SoundCloud. Not familiar with it.

Vimeo I liked the reliability of their embed player - except you couldn't customize how it looked. More importantly, you have to subscribe to their service to post HD videos - in turn this limits the sound quality you can have on your presented work online.  Youtube allows most HD types which grants you the ability to put a wider range of audio formats with your video.  Vimeo makes you pay for this. Youtube also allows the privatization of your own personal channel and only your embedded player on your website will play the video. It wont show up in searches on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Sound cloud and Vimeo - I try to avoid YouTube for my own work. Vimeo just feels more proffessional somehow if you're sending people links.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/colin-hunter) and Vimeo here too! I love how easy it is to post a soundcloud recording/clip on a blog. Plus the sample rate and bit depth are not limited, it's only the length in time. This is a big advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer vimeo to youtube. Youtube places a 15 minute limit on videos you upload. Vimeo does not have this length restriction. You are restriced by file size... but it's a fairly generous file size.

Answer (score 0):

I use YouTube as another social outlet to show my work. I'm starting to use SoundCloud. I'm all for trying to make it easier for my clients. They can send me the files I need without having to log in to an ftp. I'm trying to add it to my Facebook account... but this is no picnic!

Answer (score 0):

I use Vimeo and Soundcloud. Its great because these sites are so quick easy to upload a video and track. I use them both to get quick advice and comments on my works and to share files with others. Plus they look nicer than youtube. Also Soundcloud looks good and is easy to use right there without following a link when you put it up on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

For sound designers, there is fantastic exposure available on youtube.  Because, this is where the filmmakers go .. right?  Who do you want to promote yourself to as a sound designer?  Filmmakers, film producers, video editors.

Sure, there are tons of irrelevant visitors but who knows what opportunities lurk in those visits.
Personally I post free sfx on youtube and have had over 300,000 views this year alone which is great for branding and driving traffic to my sound effects site.

Check it out, completely free promo and branding.

http://www.youtube.com/sfxsource

Soundcloud is an amazing service and site.  But, if you are looking for exposure to video editors, filmmakers etc .. folks who might hire you, its not necessarily the most direct option .. I get a sense its a fantastic platform for composers or for generating a fan base if you are a musician